# Which email account will be used for sending email using email router in Dynamics CRM 2011?

Tags: email, android-activity, dynamics-crm-2011

I am going to send emails using email router. But unable to find out which the email account the email router used to send the email. I want to seek your kind help and suggestions in this regard.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define an account to the email router. Check this [tutorial](http://osmosee.wordpress.com/2012/07/28/configuring-e-mail-router-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-online-with-exchange-online-office-365/) to see how.